# iOS: Making multiple NSURLSession request

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

I need to make multiple http request but I need to wait for response of the request to move on to the next one but I can not figure out how to do it. Does any body knows how can I do this without using dispatch_semaphore

This is my code:

```
-(void)multipleReques:(NSArray*)arrayUrl
{
    __block NSInteger *countFailures = 0;

    for (NSString *urlStr in arrayUrl)
    {

        NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                          if (error)
                                          {
                                              countFailures++;
                                          }
                                      }];
        [task resume];
    }
}
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nested completion blocks? Delegates?

Comment: @Zhi-WeiCai do you have and example?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it: (Just a quick demo, not sure if it executed at all)

```
// Global variables somewhere...
NSUInteger progress;
NSUInteger failures;

- (void)myFunction
{
  // ...
  progress = 0;
  failures = 0;
  [self makeRequestWithURLs:@[...]]; // an array of NSURLs.
  // ...
}

- (void)makeRequestWithURLs:(NSURL *)arrayOfURLs
{
  if ([arrayOfURLs count] <= progress) {
    return;
  }

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:arrayOfURLs[progress]];
  NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] 
  dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, 
                                                  NSURLResponse *response, 
                                                  NSError *error) 
  {
    if (error) {
      failures++;
    } else {
      progress++;
      [self makeRequestWithURLs:arrayOfURLs];
    }
  }];
  [task resume];
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example to do it with delegates ?

Comment: Nope, as there were way too many possible ways to do it. Didn't the answer above solve your problem? You have to come up with a solution that best suit your needs. Delegate or not there's no one stop solution for all purposes.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the maximum number of connections per host to 1?  I would expect that to have the desired effect, so long as if the request fails, you cancel all of the other outstanding requests in the session from within the delegate method that handles the initial response from the server.

Comment: Except completion handler blocks, there's no way you can make sure you finished them one by one.